# Stack another page on top of my page with iframe or lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a problem with loading another page above my page. I did try the iframe method, and it kind of works. Iframe will show over full screen but the content that is on my page will also show bellow that iframe when I scroll to the bottom of the page... Is there any way to put iframe on top of this content or there is better way with maybe lightbox or something like that. I'm new to the coding game and was having hard time with just iframe to show over whole page...

This is the code that used in template that I created for this purpose.

```
<?php
/**
Template Name: Content Only
*/
?>
<html>
<head>
   <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); bloginfo('url'); ?></title>
   <style>
       html,body,div,iframe {height:100%;}
       p {position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
       iframe {border:none;width:100%;}
       body {margin:0;padding:0;}
   </style>
</head>

<body>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); endwhile; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Then I insert iframe in text editor on page I want to show iframe and there is iframe but also the content bellow the iframe (and double scroll bar).

I would like to have a code that will put other site above (in front of) my site.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a comment:
What exactly are trying to achieve?
By your reference to lightbox...I'am guessing you are trying to create a modal.
Try these:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but I managed to do what had to be done by tweaking the code. Everything is working like it should.
This is what i changed:

```
html,body,div,iframe {height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
p {overflow:hidden;}
iframe {z-index:1000;border:none;width:100%;}
```